# Coinbase price discrepancy?

Tags: trading, coinbase.com

At the moment the price of a bitcoin on the Coinbase dashboard is $8247 EUR, however in the buy section it's $8840 EUR.  I know they have some commissions and spreads, but that's 7%... Is this a bug or a feature?

Moreover, the sell price is $8755 EUR! Much higher than the market price! I even bought some for 10 dollars to make sure. In GDAX, which is Coinbase's exchange the price is $8244.  Why does Coinbase sell/buy for so high?

Answer (score 1):

When you buy from Coinbase, you are buying from a service provider, not from a person who is selling....so, yes, you will be paying more.

Don't ever actually buy from Coinbase (or sell); they mark up the price that is set on THEIR OWN exchange, GDAX. It literally only takes you seconds and zero cost to transfer your funds from Coinbase over to GDAX to trade yourself at a better rate, so there's no reason to take the Coinbase markup.